# Right way to do End to End tests with Jenkins

Tags: javascript, php, jenkins, e2e-testing

I have an app using PHP and ReactJS for the frontend. I have unit tests for the PHP project and e2e for the frontend project. I deploy my project using Jenkins and Docker for the app.

When a developer push on a branch, I'd like to run the tests (unit, e2e) in the CI. If everything is OK, we can deploy the project. I'd like to know the right way to do that ?

Today I am doing these steps :

- one dev pushes the code, the job "test-app" is triggered in jenkins
- the job build the docker image in a "dev" environment, with the dev dependencies in PHP
- the app is started, let's say the url is "tests-app.com"
- the tests are executed (unit, e2e using Selenium and tests-app.com)
- the tests are OK, a job "app-deploy" is triggered and "tests-app.com" is shut down
- the job app-deploy build the docker image in a "prod" environment, without the dev dependencies in PHP
- the app is started the url is now "app.com"

Is that the right way to do that ? From the push by the developer and the end of the Jenkins builds it can take 5-10 minutes.

Comment: LGTM, but in IMHO, I suggest run unit tests before docker build image. If there is an error in unit test, the job will fail early

Comment: Yeah sure. So you think I should run unit tests during the build of the image ? I have a "RUN composer install" and then a "RUN venbor/bin/phpunit" ? If this last RUN fails, the image is not build entirely and the jenkins job fails.